# Equality of modulus of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Let z by any point on the circle $z=z_0+\rho e^{i\theta}$. Let p and q are inverse points with respect to this circle. Therefore the points p,q and $z_0$ are co-linear and then $p=z_0+re^{i\phi}$ and $q=z_0+\frac {\rho^2}{r}e^{\phi}$ for some r<$\rho$ Then,
$$\frac {z-p}{z-q} = \frac {(z-z_0)-(p-z_0)}{(z-z_0)-(q-z_0)} = \frac {r}{\rho}\frac {\rho e^{i\theta}-re^{i\phi}}{re^{i\theta}-\rho e^{i\phi}} $$
where now taking modulus yields according to the book I am studying,
$$ \left|\frac{z-p}{z-q}\right| = \frac r\rho$$
I want to know why the $$\left|\frac {\rho e^{i\theta}-re^{i\phi}}{re^{i\theta}-\rho e^{i\phi}}\right|$$ is one

**My Approach:** I used geometry to prove that the numerator is equal to the denominator. I don't know how to sketch the diagram so I am unable to show my result but I think there is a much simpler approach as to why the modulus is one which I am not getting as the book didn't even bother mentioning it.

*Also, please suggest how can I sketch complicated mathematics diagram here. Do I need to learn LaTex or there is any alternative*

Comment: Q: what kind of mathematical diagrams you want to sketch?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Like anything from simple 2D shapes to graphs of functions to contours diagrams with text on it so that I can use it in future as an image in my questions or answers here for better visual understanding.

Comment: I like GeoGebra. It is free interactive mathematics software solution (for learning and teaching science, technology, engineering, and mathematics from primary school up to the university level). Next, you can try: https://www.diagrams.net/
free, high quality diagramming software for flowcharts or diagrams, which allow online collaboration as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex numbers $z, w$ is
$$
 |z-w|^2 = (z-w)(\bar z - \bar w) = |z|^2 + |w|^2 -2 \operatorname{Re}(z \bar w) \, .
$$
Using this formula you can verify that both $|\rho e^{i\theta}-re^{i\phi}|^2$ and $|re^{i\theta}-\rho e^{i\phi}|^2$ are equal to
$$
 \rho^2 + r^2 - 2\rho r \cos(\theta-\phi)
$$
so that the quotient is equal to one.

Alternatively, write
$$
\frac {\rho e^{i\theta}-re^{i\phi}}{re^{i\theta}-\rho e^{i\phi}}
= - \frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\phi}} \cdot 
\frac {\rho -re^{i(\phi-\theta)}}{\rho -re^{i(\theta-\phi)}}
$$
and note that the second factor has modulus one because the numerator is the complex conjugate of the denominator.